# how to append a dynamically created div more than one div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my application i am creating a div dynamically. And i want to append that dynamically  created div to more than one div in html. but it is always appending to only one div. i want same div in two divs. i have serched many ways any one please help me.

here is the example

```
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <script>
    var div= document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML="HIIIIIIII";
    document.getElementById("1").appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById("2").appendChild(div);
    </script>
```

div is always appending to id=2 div

Comment: You create one node, you can only put it in one place.

Comment: [Clone that node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) ... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/knn9S/)

Answer (score 0):

because  appendChild function 
change the address of the parent container of parameter that passed to it.
so when you pass the div element created by document.createElement()
in second call of appendChild acttualy you changed the parent address of  it

you must create another instance of div to append for second time